# How can I split a List<T> into two lists, one containing all duplicate values and the other containing the remainder?

Tags: c#, linq, list, duplicates

I have a basic class for an Account (other properties removed for brevity):

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<T>` of these accounts.

I can remove duplicates based on the e-mail address easily:

```
var uniques = list.GroupBy(x => x.Email).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

The list named 'uniques' now contains only one of each account based on e-mail address, any that were duplicates were discarded.

I want to do something a little different and split the list into two.
One list will contain only 'true' unique values, the other list will contain **all** duplicates.

For example the following list of Account e-mails:

> unique@email.com
>   dupe@email.com
>   dupe@email.com

Would be split into two lists:

> **Unique**
>   unique@email.com
>
> **Duplicates**
>   dupe@email.com
>   dupe@email.com

I have been able to achieve this already by creating a list of unique values using the example at the top. I then use `.Except()` on the original list to get the differences which are the duplicates. Lastly I can loop over each duplicate to 'pop' it out of the unique list and move it to the duplicate list.

[Here is a working example on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MCa9lb)

**Can I split the list in a more efficient or syntactically sugary way?**

I'd be happy to use a third party library if necessary but I'd rather just stick to pure LINQ.
I'm aware of CodeReview but feel the question also fits here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var duplicates = list.GroupBy(x => x) // or x.Property if you are grouping by some property.
                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                     .SelectMany(g => g);

var uniques = list.GroupBy(x => x) // or x.Property if you are grouping by some property.
                  .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                  .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Alternatively, once you get one list, you can get the other one using `Except`:

```
var uniques = list.Except(duplicates);
// or
var duplicates = list.Except(uniques);
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to specify that it's based on the `Email` property of the `Account`.

Comment: D'uh, I'm being an idiot. Apologies. This works fantastically, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `list.Except(duplicates)` give you the uniques? Note, I did not try it so there may be some nuance here I missed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: returns the same result.

Answer (score 6):

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.Email)
                 .GroupBy(g => g.Count() == 1 ? 0 : 1)
                 .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                 .Select(g => g.SelectMany(x => x))
                 .ToList();
```

`groups[0]` will be the unique ones and `group[1]` will be the non-unique ones.

Comment: You can use `.GroupBy(g => g.Count == 1)` and `groups[true]` will be the uniques, `groups[false]` the duplicates.

Comment: @JacobKrall No it would still be `groups[0]` and `groups[1]` unless you used `ToDictionary` instead of `ToList`. Plus I don't like to have to look up which comes first (true or false) so I just make it explicit.

Comment: That's fair enough.

Comment: This doesn't compile, though -- `Count` doesn't exist (use the LINQ extension method `Count()`, and `SelectMany()` isn't a valid overload, you have to pass a selector

Comment: @JacobKrall Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to get uniques, and then for duplicates simply get the elements in the original list that aren't in uniques.

```
IEnumerable<Account> uniques;
IEnumerable<Account> dupes;
dupes = list.Where(d => 
         !(uniques = list.GroupBy(x => x.Email)
                         .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                         .SelectMany(u => u))
         .Contains(d));
```